# How to hide files and folders in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, directory, root, hidden-files

I want to hide, most of the folders in root (`/`) using Nautilus. Probably the only folders in `/` I want shown are `/home` and `/tmp`.

In addition to hiding *folders*, I also want to hide two files: `initrd.img` and `initrd.img.old`.

I find such a setup to be pro-noob, and looks a lot slicker too. How can I hide those folders and files?

Comment: Do you want to hide it in your file manager (e.g. Gnome's Nautilus or KDE's Dolphin) or for the whole system? As far as I know, the latter is not possible ([Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)).

Comment: Any file-manager. But i am using nautilus. So if i can hide folders only in nautilus. i am happy! :)

Comment: @blade19899 Then your own answer is correct. Works here. Please update your question to be Nautilus.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Tested under Nautilus 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 (but works in almost all scenarios)*

Open `gnome-terminal` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Type `ls -1 /`.

Copy the name(s) of the folder(s) you want hidden.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type in `gedit`.

Paste all the names you want hidden like so:

> [image: hidden]

<sup>**Image excerpted from [Another Way to Hide Files Folders in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuguide.net/another-way-to-hide-files-folders-in-ubuntu) by [Meilin](http://ubuntuguide.net/author/admin)**</sup>

Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) in the directory `/` with the name `.hidden` (no asterisk, as seen in the image above).

Refresh the page, and they are gone.

> [image: hidden-folders]

<sup>Image from [How to hide files and folders - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/how-to-hide-files-and-folders)</sup>

**If you want them unhidden later...**

To unhide the folders, you can either:

- remove there names from the `.hidden` file, *or*
- just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view all hidden files and folders.

**Reference:**

- [Meilin](http://ubuntuguide.net/author/admin), "[Another Way to Hide Files Folders in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuguide.net/another-way-to-hide-files-folders-in-ubuntu)," [*Ubuntu Sharing (ubuntuguide.net)*](http://ubuntuguide.net/).
- [How to hide files and folders - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/how-to-hide-files-and-folders)

Comment: Works perfectly in Nautilus. Please mention the filename should be ``.hidden`` (without the asterisk as in the screenshot). F5 (refresh) seems enough to make Nautilus aware of it. And it works like opt-out, not opt-in unfortunately.

Comment: "Save the file (Ctrl+S) in the directory /" ... That should be placed in `~` or `$HOME`, and not `/`

Comment: @gertvdijk: just to clarify, the asterisk shown in the screenshot is not part of the filename, it's just a Gedit UI indicator that the file has changed and not yet saved.

Comment: Seems to work in Thunar as well

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can achieve this easily, this is either all or nothing in the unix model, and there is no permission for "seeing content of directory". Once you have enough access to read a directory, then you can read everything ( ie, the list of folder/files )

chmod o-r / could work for hiding all directories, but I do not recommend to do it without testing first on a vm, and fully understanding what you do.

Using a custom kernel module, you could hide folders, but that's rather complex and error prone.

Comment: Would given a dot in front of the folder help. like so '.media'

Comment: That would requires change the path on every program ( ie, /.etc is different from /etc ), so all programs would likely be broken and the system would not boot.

Comment: ;( to bad i will try some stuff out in virtual-box using 12.04 amd64 i will post later with the results.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an extension to @blade19899's answer*

### Motivation

Putting file names in `.hidden` file will hide them but nautilus only checks for exact matches. In some scenarios we want to hide files by pattern, not by exact names—for example I don't like to see latex aux files.

### Workaround

My workaround is to split the `.hidden` in two sections
separated by a line of at least 5 equal signs (i.e. `=====`). The patterns
should be placed before this separator. Then, an script (see below) completes
the file by adding exact filenames after the separator.

In practice, you need to run this script manually to update the file
with new matches. Maybe adding this file as a FilemanagerActions would
be a good idea.

### Script

Run with no arguments:

```
import glob
from pathspec import PathSpec


def main():
    patterns = find_patterns('.hidden')
    files = ls()
    matches = find_matches(patterns, files)
    update_dothidden(patterns, matches)


def find_patterns(filepath):
    patterns = []
    with open(filepath) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line[0:5] == '=====':
            break
        patterns.append(line)
    return patterns


def ls():
    return glob.iglob('**/**', recursive=True)


def find_matches(patterns, files):
    path_spec = PathSpec.from_lines('gitwildmatch', patterns)
    return filter(path_spec.match_file, files)


def update_dothidden(patterns, matches):
    with open('.hidden', 'w') as f:
        for pattern in patterns:
            f.write(pattern)
        f.write('======================\n\n')
        for match in matches:
            f.write(match + '\n')
        f.write("\n# For usage, see https://github.com/m2-farzan/dothidden-patterns")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Latest version of the script: https://github.com/m2-farzan/dothidden-patterns/blob/main/refresh_dothidden.py*

### Example

Put this into `.hidden` file:

```
*.aux
*.bbl
*.blg
*.log
*.synctex.gz
```

Execute:

```
~/my_scripts/refresh_dothidden.py
```

Updated `.hidden` file:

```
*.aux
*.bbl
*.blg
*.log
*.synctex.gz
======================

dstar_main.aux
main.aux
main.bbl
main.blg
main.log
main.synctex.gz
mrpp_central.aux
tikzhead.aux
```