# Hide certain files and folders?

Tags: files, directory

[image]

**Selected Files/folders:**

I don't know who these files belong to, but I'm afraid deleting them might cause something to break. How do I hide these files and folders so that they do not appear in Nautilus, but they are accessible by Windows, if they belong to it.

I have seen some guides where each file and folder to be hidden is prepended by a period (.), but that would change the file name, which may or may not break something.

Comment: See this question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/143315/hide-some-folder-in-root/187316#187316

Comment: you might want to try the link, I gave you, to hide those folders! I think it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look like the relatively new Windows bootlader files.
You're right that you shouldn't rename them, e.g. by inserting a dot before the name in order to hide them under Linux.

To hide otherwise in a GUI way, you can install **Nautilus Actions Extra** by first adding the repository using these terminal commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

You can then install **Nautilus Actions Extra** using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions-extra
```

You can install **nautilus-hide** only instead of the whole package using this terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-hide
```

Finally, you'll get **(Un)Hide** option in Nautilus context menu to hide any folder(s) and/or file(s) selected after restarting Nautilus with this terminal command:

```
nautilus -q
```

Comment: I am not near a Ubuntu machine, so i can't check this, but I think at the top of my head, that that nautilus-hide package also set a `.` infront of the name!?

Comment: No, it doesn't! It uses another method: A plain text file named ".hidden" is created in the location where you have files and folders to hide, and then simply their names are listed in this file. So, in a non-gui way, you can just do this manually as well ;-)

Comment: Hey, this works. Thanks! I do have another question though. I can't seem to launch the actions-config-tool with the command `gksu nautilus-actions-config-tool`. Any help with that?

Comment: No need for gksu - those settings should only apply to **that** user who wants them. Please in the future ask a new question - makes it easier for all who seek solutions later