# Hiding files in Nautilus using .hidden does not work

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files

On my Windows network drives, some folders have a large number of files beginning with ~$. I would like to hide these files in Nautilus.

I've tried adding the file names to a `.hidden` file (as documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143315/how-to-hide-files-and-folders-in-nautilus?rq=1)), but it doesn't seem to recognize them, I'm assuming because of the tilde in front. Is there a way to either make the file names be recognized from the `.hidden` file, or to add a rule to Nautilus to hide such file prefixes?

Comment: It might be (just guessing here, didn't look this up in the Nautilus documentation) that the reason that hiding these files by listing them in a file called `.hidden` does not work is that Nautilus interprets the lines listed as regular expressions, so the `$` in the filename is interpreted specially (not the tilde, which does not have specific meaning). Could you try listing them as `~\$.*` and see if this works?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what those files do for Windows, that might be the reason.  If you're NOT dual booting and/or you know that they're not system files that your Windows installation would need, you can try to put them in a .hidden folder to see if that works