# How can I change or hide the ~/snap directory?

Tags: configuration, home-directory, snap, default

I'm not particularly fond of apps cluttering my `$HOME` directory with their own files or directories. It's rarely a problem, because most apps have the courtesy to hide their data by prefixing it with a dot or conforming to the `~/.config` standard. But not snap.

**Q1**: Have I misunderstood this directory?  Is `~/snap` really a directory which I'm supposed to enter and access on a daily basis on a par with `~/downloads`, `~/pictures`, `~/work`, etc?

**Q2**: In any case: Can I rename it to e.g. `~/.snap`?  I can't find anything like `/etc/snap`, `/etc/default/snap`, or `~/.config/snap` to tweak things. I tried `export SNAP_USER_DATA=$HOME/.snap` but it didn't work.

Comment: It can't. But I don't have just this one file in my home dir, I have quite a lot. And many a little makes a mickle. Furthermore I have configured my system so that not $HOME/Desktop but $HOME directly is shown on my desktop because it makes more sense to me this way, but this also means that unwanted directories and files here will be even more visible and annoying. And then there's this whole thing about apps should hide their configuration files.

Comment: Or thinking about it this way: Suddenly someone walks in, puts a box on your table, and walks out again without a word. Don't you think that at some point you'd find that box got in you way and would want to remove it? =) I for sure like to decide what goes on my own table, and similarly what files are (visible) in my $HOME.

Comment: Trololo? Run this in your home folder and you'll see what happens if every program just created one single folder in your home dir: ```for f in .*; do g="${f#.}"; echo "How can a single file clutter your home folder? It's just ${g}." ; echo ln -sv "$f" "${g}_"; done```

 This is actually harmless to run, but you should remove the last `echo` there and I think you'll "buy my line of thought".

Comment: Right... So half of the conversation has been deleted which makes me look rather skizofrenic =). But for the record, the initial and follow-up comment sounded something like "How can one file clutter your home dir? [...] I still don't buy your line of thought".

Comment: They are currently claiming a "workaround" of "making the folder 'hidden'" (https://cialu.net/how-to-move-snap-folder-away-from-home-location-in-linux/) but the "workaround" is not a workaround, and doesn't make the folder hidden, it just removes it from displays in graphic file managers but of course the directory is still there, still called "~/snap", and still brazenly visible in the home directory to CLI.

Comment: It's the same workaround that had been mentioned in a couple of the answers here. And like you concluded yourself, it's not a very good one.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

So..

**A1**: No; `~/snap` is not supposed to be accessed manually on a daily basis; it's a  settings directory.

**A2**:  No; `~/snap` cannot be changed; it's cluttering your home dir by design.

**However**
there is already a bug report on this issue, but it's currently only prioritized as *wishlist*. If you're affected by this bug (and you *are* if you have a `~/snap` =) then let the kind developers know, and encourage them to fix the bug by raising its significance:

1. Go to **[the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1575053)**
2. Login to Launchpad (top right corner).
3. Click **This bug affects N people. Does this bug affect you?** (near top left)
4. Click **Yes, this bug affects me**

**In the meantime** do like @Rinzwind suggests and simply hide the directory from Nautilus by typing this in a shell:

```
echo snap >> ~/.hidden
```

**Alternative get *completely* rid of snap** by downright uninstalling *everything* related snap, as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114686/344227).

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing out that bug report.  Believe me, if a snap directory appears in my $HOME when I install a snap, I can confidently say that I won't ever use this technology. If, as I suspect, this becomes a concrete piece of the Ubuntu landscape, I'll have to rethink my decades-long commitment to the platform. Crazy decision.

Comment: Just voted as well - seems like something might be happening. I'll repeat from Stephan's comment in the bug report: "It's 2017, come on."

Comment: It's 2019, and still no progress on this. Come on! Purging snap right now.

Comment: it's the arrogance of it that's most irritating. Uninstalling.

Comment: Exactly! "So what if we pooped in your homedir? Deal with it!". Which brings us here.

Comment: I actually completely removed snap only because of the described issue. I used it to install Google Chrome, but f*ck that if this isn't fixed...

Comment: This also works well with KDE / Kubuntu's Dolphin file manager. Thanks!

Comment: Something is happening: https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/10836

Answer (score 31):

> Q1: Have I misunderstood this directory? Is ~/snap really a directory which I'm supposed to enter and access on a daily basis on a par with ~/downloads, ~/work, ~/tmp, etc?

It is a regular directory but is not really meant for user access. It is managed by the `snapd` utility. [It seems likely it will be renamed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1575053) to `~/.snap` at some point. Or less likely to `~/.local/share/snap`.

> Q2: In any case: How do I hide it?

When it is renamed it will be hidden automatically.

To hide from the desktop shell for now, create a text file called `~/.hidden` and put the word "snap" in it. [This will hide the "~/snap" folder from Nautilus.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143315)

To hide from the command line for now, alias `ls` to `ls -Isnap`. Now "snap" will be ignored when `ls`-ing.

Comment: "alias ls to ls -Isnap" Note that it will hide "snap" wherever you run ls, not only in the $HOME directory. The real solution belongs to snap.

Comment: This solution does not show show the snap directory, but it also ignores the color preferences I have saved for different file types, i.e. there is no way to visually distinguish between files and directories. Any tips?

Comment: @NicholasCousar run `alias ls` before setting the new alias, this will show you the existing alias (probably `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`). You can then add the option at the end, `alias ls='ls --color=auto -Isnap'`

Comment: Thanks for the `~/.hidden` solution, good enough for me.

Answer (score 5):

All snap applications themselves (in case they are installed) are located in the `/snap` directory.
`/home/user/snap` contains your personal settings of those snaps (in case they are installed).
The `/home/user/snap` folder was created once when you've installed the first `snap` package.

In case you don't have snap applications installed, you can delete the `/home/user/snap` folder.
If you install and use new snap applications, the folder will be re-created - this is done by design.
As `snapd` is "work in progress" - maybe another default directory can be selected in the future.

Comment: If you desire a configuration option for this, I'd recommend filing a bug against snapd itself, here:- https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bugs

Comment: @popey Way ahead of you =) I even found out someone already filed a bug report.  I'm answering my own question with instructions on how to encourage the developers to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

This is currently possible as an experimental feature flag.

```
$ sudo snap set system experimental.hidden-snap-folder=true
```

The flag can also be disabled by running.

```
$ sudo snap unset system experimental.hidden-snap-folder
```

Comment: Interesting!  I don't know what to think of this.  I mean, the mere fact than this has taken 5 years to implement and it still considered experimental feature suggest that this is a hack.  It will probably just be `~/.snap` instead of `~/.config/share/snap`.  And maybe that's fine, I don't know anymore; I'm mad at snap and got tired fighting it so I switched to Arch.  No matter what: Congratz on your first post.  I's nice and complete! =)

Answer (score -2):

I think I actually have a solution for this! Well kinda. There's a Nautilus extension called "Nautilus Hide" that will hide files and folders without changing their name. It basically writes the name of the folder to a file that Nautilus uses to see if a folder should be hidden or not.

Works like a charm!

https://github.com/brunonova/nautilus-hide

Comment: I'm unsure what to make of this. While this does answer half of the question's title, it doesn't address any of the two questions in the body. You describe another work-around to hide a directory in Nautilus though (what I see is) a user-friendly plug-in for users who aren't comfortable with shell one-liners (ie. `echo snap >> ~/.hidden`) ... but do know their way around `git`, `cmake` and `sudo make install`.  I guess this adds *something* new to the table.

Comment: Sometimes you want to hide and unhide a folder without having to pull up your CLI yah know? It's faster to right click on something and say hide than it is to open a program and type out a command. At least for me.

Comment: You say "sometimes", but this question is all about *one single directory*. And you still have to "pull up the CLI" to do the work you propose, and you're need to install git to pull it, and the whole build system to compile it, and finally run `sudo` to install it. This is far more complicated. At least for me.

Comment: Cool, Don't really see why it's worth a downvote though. Seems to not fall within the community guidelines. My solution isn't wrong and may be considered useful to someone else who views this page.

Comment: Your solution to add `snap` to `~/.hidden` was already explained in two existing answers; only difference is that your approach is *way more complicated*. I don't find that useful, I wouldn't recommend this approach to anyone, hence -1 to usefulness.

Answer (score -2):

To hide from the command line for now, alias `ls` to `ls -I snap --color=tty`

This can show the color preference.

Comment: This answer has already been suggested.  The added `--color=tty` doesn't have anything to do with the issue at hand. Otherwise, welcome =)