# How to remove snap from Ubuntu?

Tags: snap, software-uninstall

How do I remove `snap`? `apt` pretends it's not there, but I can still call commands with it.

Trying to remove it says `read only file system`

```
# apt remove snap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'snap' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
# snap whoami
email: -
```

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The package is not called [`snap`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/snap), but instead is [`snapd`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/snapd).

You will want to do

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

After that, run the following command so that Ubuntu does not automatically install snapd as an update.

```
sudo apt-mark hold snapd
```

---

**Additional comments**:

1. Ubuntu 22.04 has Firefox as a snap app, as a part of the default installation. If you try `sudo apt install firefox`, it will reinstall snap without asking you. [Follow this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401) to install Firefox as an apt package.
2. Also, since removing snap will also remove `snap-store`, you may want to install `gnome-software` as a GUI app store.

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-software --no-install-recommends
   ```

`--no-install-recommends` ensures that it will not pull snap plugin once again.

3. To prevent Ubuntu from automatically reinstalling snapd in future, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1345401/124466)

Comment: Why `--purge`? The OP didn't say the removal must also remove the configs.

Comment: @Ruslan  If the configs are left, apparmor crashes on startup in this case.

Comment: Will this prevent future system updates? Oftentimes the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package gets deleted for things like this and you are forced to re-install it later on if you want to upgrade. Will that be the case here?

Comment: Removal of a metapackage does not prevent updating of packages which it originally installed, no.

Comment: WATCH OUT: I did this to uninstall wechat, but it also automatically deleted skype, slack, spotify, and a lot of other gnome features!

Comment: @pietro This is not for removing individual snaps, but to remove all snaps and support thereof, from the system. If you want to remove individual snaps, you need to do so with `snap remove` instead.

Comment: @dobey yes you're right, I realized that only later. What I meant to say with my comment is that if you use the code that you (correctly) suggested, then watch out because it might have unintended consequences. I didn't know that slack, spotify, etc on my machine were installed with snap

Comment: It's important to note that this will only remove snaps in the present moment. Dependencies might pull it in automatically in future apt operations (apt does tell you and prompt you but apparently nobody reads that). If you want snaps to never reappear again, you must tell apt that using [apt_preferences(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html). Maybe someone can test and provide the exact solution for that on this page?

Comment: You may want to add `sudo apt-mark hold snapd` to make sure it doesn't inadvertently come back.

Comment: lxd user may need to be deleted also.

Comment: You may also want to remove `/snap/bin` from your PATH. It is hardcoded in `/etc/environment` and `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: FYI Mozilla now offers native debian packages: https://blog.mozilla.org/en/products/4-reasons-to-try-mozillas-new-firefox-linux-package-for-ubuntu-and-debian-derivatives/

Answer (score 132):

**TL;DR:**

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd/

sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap

rm -fr ~/snap

sudo apt-mark hold snapd
```

This will completely remove `snap`, `snapd`, all installed snap packages *and* their data, and never again suggest snap packages in the software store.
Finally, it will block `snapd` package from ever being installed again.

Your output of `mount`, `df` and `cat /proc/partitions` will thank you ;)

**Optionally**

Test that the block works by trying to install the `chromium-browser`, which (at the time of writing) suddenly depends on the `snapd` and will drag everything just uninstalled back into your system upon installation:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

The installation should fail.

Comment: My output of mount, df and cat /proc/partitions thanks you :)

Comment: This does not work: `rm: cannot remove '/snap/lxd/10343/zfs-0.8/lib/libzpool.so.2.0.0': Read-only file system` -- for example.

Comment: Perhaps in your case you need to gracefully uninstall all snaps before removing snapd itself -- and not just brutally rip it out like I did.  A combination of `sudo snap list`, a loop, and `sudo snap remove $package` should do it, but I don't have snap installed, so unfortunately I cannot get more concrete that this =\

Comment: I had to manually `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd/` before I could actually purge `snapd` (Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: @Murphy Thanks, I've added it. Did you experience any problems like Zelphir? Did you uninstall all snaps before uninstalling snapd itself?

Comment: No, and no. But I only had one installed, `pycharm`.

Comment: My FAT has just gone on a diet.

Comment: In my case, the `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd/` was not needed, as `--purge` did cleanup that directory

Comment: lxd user may need to be deleted also.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if you asked especially for this, but if you just want to remove showing snap packages in Software (gnome-software; as I wanted to), you can just uninstall snap plugin with command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

I don't know if `--purge` is necessary, but it works fine - Software doesn't show now packages from Snap Store, but I can still install them by command line with `snap install [something]`

Answer (score 11):

I have just installed a server and apparently it also comes pre-installed with snaps that besides being useless are also blocking the shutdown of the device.

[This very good blog post](https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-snaps-in-ubuntu-20-10-and-20-04-lts/) has instructions for cleaning up your system. It basically says:

```
snap list
sudo snap remove each_item # (by dependency order)
sudo umount /snap/core/xxxx # On 20.04, on 20.10 /var/snap
sudo apt purge snapd
```

Clear various files at `/home/*/snap`, `/usr/lib/snap` and alike

```
rm -rf ~/snap
sudo rm -rf /snap
sudo rm -rf /var/snap
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/snapd
```

In case of the server the only snap was `lxd` (something Canonical is pushing as an alternative to docker).

IMHO this a bit of a conflict of interest between Canonical and the users. Users should be able to opt-in whatever they need and not be forced to uninstall stuff the hard way.

In any case, at least for the moment this is reversible. You can remove specific packages and the snap daemon and install later if needed.

Comment: The blog instructions might work if you've got a clean system, but don't work if you've installed a snap yourself. Some of the snap items can't be removed.

Comment: The key in to remove each_item # (by dependency order). 
You can try removing all packages then repeat for the ones that had dependencies. Probably will be done in a couple of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I have a short script that removes all existing snaps and afterwards snapd can normally be removed.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

# snaps can only be removed if they have no other snaps
# depending on them. We use a brute force approach and
# just try to uninstall them multiple times.
#
# try at most 30 times to uninstall all snaps
MAX_TRIES=30

for try in $(seq 1 $MAX_TRIES); do
  INSTALLED_SNAPS=$(snap list 2> /dev/null | grep -c  ^Name || true)
  if (( $INSTALLED_SNAPS == 0 )); then
    echo "all snaps removed"
    exit 0
  fi
  echo "Attempt $try of $MAX_TRIES to remove $INSTALLED_SNAPS snaps."


  # we ignore error during uninstall as we are retrying in the loop
  snap list 2> /dev/null | grep -v ^Name |  awk '{ print $1 }'  | xargs -r -n1  snap remove || true
done

echo "ERROR: Unable to uninstall"
exit 1
```