# What is all this /snap gibberish mounted on my system?

Tags: snap

What on earth is all this utter gibber on my (freshly booted) ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine, and how do I make it go away and never bother me again?

```
/dev/loop0               3840       3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop1               3840       3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/45
/dev/loop2              13312      13312          0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop3               3840       3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/41
/dev/loop4              88704      88704          0 100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop5             144384     144384          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop6              22144      22144          0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/31
/dev/loop7             142848     142848          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/loop8              13312      13312          0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/96
/dev/loop9               2432       2432          0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/170
```

(There is lots more than this, I just included a sample).

The previous question everyone keeps saying is a duplicate doesn't say anything about how to make snap go away completely and never come back.

Comment: Snap is Canonical's latest idea of how to distribute self-updating applications. One one hand, it has the advantage that snapped applications can be kept up to date more easily; on the other hand there are some subtle differences between a snapped application and a traditionally installed application. If you don't like modern life, then `sudo apt-get --yes purge snapd` and then install the real apps with `sudo apt-get install gnome-{calculator,characters,logs,system-monitor}`.

Comment: Or just don't re-install them at all :-). I'm running the system 99% of the time in multi-user mode with no gui. Why I have to have dozens of loop mounted images when I haven't even tried to run any of the apps I don't know. What's wrong with mounting them on demand when I actually need them?

Comment: You could do as I do, and remove snapd and its dependencies. I don't use snaps and dislike the whole concept.  Removing the system is painless and has no ill effects as long as you don't want to use snaps.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-store-from-ubuntu