# All snaps are failing and I can't fix it

Tags: snap

I am sorry if this is a "too newbie" question.

I wasn't happy with snaps and I tried to delete all of them by using this line:

> sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap

which I found on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-store-from-ubuntu) of this same forum.

But now I want to go back and set my system as it was before running that line. I tried this:

> sudo apt install snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap

and though some things got fixed (like the app Software Ubuntu now looks like it used to be...thought it doest show me any snaps when I look up for them), I still can't run any snap like Mailspring or Spotify, though my system says they are actually installed.

Does anyone know how I can wipe the slate clean and have everything as if I never had ran the first line **sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap**?

I would really appreciate it.

*Added after requested:*

**Output of: sudo snap info mailspring**

```
*name:      mailspring
summary:   The best email app for people and teams at work
publisher: Mailspring (foundry376✓)
contact:   http://support.getmailspring.com/
license:   unset
description: |
  Mailspring is a desktop email client with modern features like unified
  inbox, snoozing, reminders, templates, offline search, and support for
  Gmail labels. It even has a built-in "dark" and "ubuntu" themes so you can
  style it to match your desktop. Move to Mailspring and breathe life back
  into your tired inbox!

  Provider Support:

  Mailspring is absolutely free and supports all IMAP providers, including
  Gmail, Office 365 and iCloud. Mailspring does not support Microsoft
  Exchange ActiveSync.

  Pro Version:

  If your work revolves around email, Mailspring Pro adds even more features,
  supercharging the app with read receipts, link tracking, send later,
  reminders, contact profiles, email analytics and more. At $8/mo, Mailspring
  Pro is an affordable alternative to sales and business email extensions and
  the first tool to bring all these powerful features to any IMAP providers.

  Mailspring is open-source software
  (https://github.com/Foundry376/Mailspring) and Mailspring Pro subscriptions
  allow the core maintainers to work on Mailspring and keep improvements
  coming.

  Mailspring ID:

  In order to use Mailspring, you need to create a Mailspring account.
  However, none of your email credentials or passwords are ever sent to the
  cloud. Your Mailspring ID holds things like snooze dates and mail rules, so
  you can re-install Mailspring or use it on two computers at once.

  Terms of Service:

  https://getmailspring.com/terms

  Privacy Policy:

  https://getmailspring.com/privacy-policy
commands:
  - mailspring
snap-id:      0TyNxgP6wEM3nTXzymtc1wOnvl2P6Iij
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: 2 days ago, at 12:33 CET
channels:
  stable:    1.6.0 2019-03-18 (338) 202MB -
  candidate: 1.6.0 2019-03-18 (338) 202MB -
  beta:      1.6.0 2019-03-18 (338) 202MB -
  edge:      1.6.1 2019-03-25 (343) 202MB -
installed:   1.6.0            (338) 202MB -*
```

> 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Can you add to your question, the output of `sudo snap info mailspring`

Comment: Did you, before removing snapd, also remove the installed snaps? DId you restart the system? Try removing and reinstalling the snap packages.

Comment: @Graham I don't think my problem's solution is on the thread you kindly shared.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I just added the output you requested. Do you see anything out of normal related to my problem?

Comment: @vanadium  did and tried all of those things. Snaps (fore example Mailspring) still don't open, though they appear as installed, as far as I can see. Before running the line I refer to on my question, everything was perfect and smooth. I haven't done anything else besides what I tell in the question.

Comment: Try running mailspring from the terminal. That may show error messages that point to the origin of the problem. To find the name of the executable, look in to it's desktop file. Locate the desktop file with the command `locate mailspring | grep .desktop', and open that file with an editor to see the line starting with "Exec=". After this, you will find the terminal command needed to start mailspring.

Comment: @vanadium I did what you kindly suggested. Apparently, this is the problem: <<cannot locate the core or legacy core snap>>...but, when I try to install core by running  <<sudo snap install core>>, terminal says that it is already installed, and that I should try to run <<snap help refresh>>, but from there I really don't get what I should do. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: If you have a not upt-to-date Ubuntu 16.4 version, then this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1616006) could have caused improper removal of your snaps, hence possibly breaking them when you reinstalled. There is reference to a script https://github.com/zyga/devtools/blob/master/reset-state that would reset all snap data. Also incorrect apparmor profiles could be the culprit. If this becomes too technical to solve at the system level, an easier way will be to reinstall.