# How to prohibit snap packages from being installed?

Tags: snap

I'm trying to prohibit snap packages from being installed using `/etc/apt/preferences.d/pin`:

```
Package: *
Pin: version *snap*
Pin-Priority: -10
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can [uninstall snap entirely](https://askubuntu.com/q/1035915/301745), if that's what you want

Comment: Yes i can uninstall snap entirely, but i do want, if i ask to install some package, what contains "snap" in version.

For example apt install chromium-browser/eoan

it sould be never installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99-Prohibit-Snapd` file and add the following:

```
Package: snapd
Pin: release a=*
Pin-Priority: -10
```

This config prohibits `snapd` installation completely.
So any package that depends on it will not be able to be installed and will return this error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 some-package: PreDepends: snapd but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```