# « Could not read the contents of '/media': Permission denied »

Tags: permissions

This question is NOT about access to USB or external drives.

WPS Witer and other just installed Ubuntu software can NOT open files saved on my /media directory.
I keep getting the annoying message:
« Could not read the contents of '/media': Permission denied ».

MY SIMPLE QUESTION REMAINS:

How can I access all files and folders on my user username/media/ directory?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Ubuntu's Nautilus can indeed access all files and folders in all locations. However, Ubuntu's software that I have downloaded (e.g. KRITA, WPS WRITER etc) can NOT access any file or folder on the /media directory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually **installed** those applications, or have you just downloaded a Snap? Snap applications are not actually installed, and they have well-known limitations in accessing the filesystem because they run in a sort of sandbox.

Comment: The solution is not to use snaps. I know Ubuntu people don't want to hear this, but due them being sandboxed and cannot use local resources without additional permissions.

Instead install deb (for WPS) or install from repo (for Krita). While that would simply be a `apt install krita`, I understand you want a GUI. Use Synaptics for that then.

Personally, for me, snaps were the last straw and that's why I left for Debian. Snaps have their place for proprietary software, but stuff like the calculator should not be a snap. That's my opinion.

Don't use snaps and your problems will go away.

Comment: To AlexP :  I downloaded and installed WPS Writer directly from Ubuntu Software. I still don't understand stuff about « snap » and really hope the get away from it...

Comment: A better solution is to file a bug report with the Snap author. The author did not intend use to be difficult. It's just a minor tweak to the AppArmor profile. Note that desktop application snaps are usually experimental as precisely these kinds of bugs are worked out.

Comment: To jawtheshark: Thanks for your comment. I sort of sensed this has to do with « snap » and sandboxed (new slave masters of this world...). How can I install « deb (for WPS) » ? How can I avoid  and NOT use snaps ? How can use Synaptics ? Kindly advise !

Comment: @AndréA. First uninstall the version you have right now (snap). Then download the deb file from WPS community (easy to google) and just  double click it and install normally.

Comment: Please don't ask the *same exact question* multiple times.  It's noisy and disruptive.  You should use only ***one*** question post for your question, not many.  The others have been closed and/or locked.  You should *focus* primarily on one question and not repost it.  (Please also don't use posts to dump rants in disguise as the same question as this).

Comment: As GrabrielaGarcia told you, uninstall what you have installed.  For Krita, you launch a program called "Synaptic Package Manager".  You should be able to find that by clicking on the "Activities" button, and then search for it.  I think it's installed by default.
It needs the administrative password. You normally also get an explanation popup of what it is.  Now, click "Search", and then type "Krita" and then "Search". You will get a list of results, one saying "krita".  Double click that entry and click "Mark".  Now click "Apply", and a second time "Apply".  The package will be installed.

Comment: As for WPS Office, I would recommend exactly what GabrielaGarcia wrote.  The download page is: http://wps-community.org/downloads
At the time of writing, the file "wps-office_11.1.0.8865_amd64.deb" is what you want.

To avoid snaps, avoid the store.  Ubuntu wishes to push snaps because it's their baby.  You can also fully uninstall snap support on your installation. I did.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-store-from-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks Gabriela and  jawtheshark ! I did what you advised  (uninstalled the « snap » stuff and installed wps  directly from  wps-community.org/downloads and it worked. All this for just being able to do a File > Open with a software ?!  Anyhow, thank you very much again for your prompt and clear answers.

Comment: I just want to say Thanks again to Gabriela and to jawtheshark for their clear, and insightful responses. I did what you advised above and I'm now running my WPS where I can simple do File > Open (from any location on my computer) ! Onward, I will surely steer clear of any « snap » App ...