# How to remove snap from Ubuntu 18.04 (before and after install)?

Tags: gnome, snap

I know that snap is a new way to go for Ubuntu strategy, but I am having many problems with snap approach.

Problems encountered, up to now:

1. Take 5x more time to mount a partition (lots of disk activity)
2. Many applications have permission problems, lets take gimp as an example.

   1. Gimp take 3x more time to open.  It opens NTFS partitions (and other non-local too) with permission problems, making it very difficult to save files back to it, and usually you will have to save to your local /home or loose your work.
3. Code reuse is not optimized, many say, HDD space is cheap, not true for SSD, and also in many countries HDD/SSD are very expensive.
4. If you don't use a bleeding edge hardware setup you will have very poor response time.  This is specially sad, because this is the M$ way of thinking (of doing the "consumption" trail - buy, buy, buy!).

   Notice for the readers, I do understand that SNAP and docker and similar products have the fundamental idea of solving the developer dependencies conflict problems and to try to minimize the chances to "break" installations, but we all know there are many other ways to control this, but seam to be neglected in the last few years.
5. For the original spirit of "Ubuntu" the system must be "for all" and not for the "few", so it seams to me that 'snap' is just a 'easy' way to address this paradox, but neglecting the 'many' that cannot afford a top last release, expensive, high performance hardware.

So finally, the question for this post:  how to remove snap from Ubuntu 18.04 (and later releases) before and after install, or get a non-snap release ? Where is the repository ?

Comment: All the ranting seems superfluous to (and distracts from) the actual question. Are you simply asking how to uninstall the snapd deb?

Comment: Snaps do have their problems, unfortunately some programs are only available as a snap.  You will need to make sure the software you use has another method of installing.  Chromium is an example.  To remove snaps, can google or see this link.    https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-store-from-ubuntu?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove `snap` first you might want to remove all the snap programs to free up storage space. To do so here is a small script.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal
2. Type the command

   ```
   nano script.sh
   ```
3. Paste the contents to the script

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/sh
   set -eu
   snap list --all |
       while read snapname revision; do
           snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
       done
   ```
4. Save the script by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   5.Now, run the script using

   ```
   bash script.sh
   ```
5. Afterwards, remove snap using

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
   ```

Comment: an [alternative aproach](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114686/822036) to uninstalling

Comment: @BinarWeb if you had taken the patience to read the comments on the 'alternative approach', let me quote Stephan Henningsen's reply "you need to gracefully uninstall all snaps before removing `snapd` itself -- and not just brutally rip it out like I did". On the other hand, the script I mentioned will first remove all the packages installed from the snap store and then remove snap store itself.

Comment: There is a slight problem with the formatting, the code-blocks are sticking out at the left. Since all the code-blocks here correspond to the previous numbered list item, they should be contained inside the space for the associated numbered list item (i.e. indentation needed). I could have edited it, but seems you're not very keen on others editing your posts (evident from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1193569/revisions) and the [other one](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1199080/revisions)), which is kinda disappointing and that's not how Stack Exchange sites work.