# How do I remove all snaps and snapd, preferably with a single command

Tags: snap

I'm currently using a Ubuntu 20.04 machine with a small root volume. The default snap setup occupies ~1G space, though with only a few packages. And when I tried to remove `core` from snap I got the following error.

```
# snap remove core18
error: cannot remove "core18": snap "core18" is not removable: snap is being used by snaps gnome-3-34-1804, gtk-common-themes and snap-store.
```

I understand I can work around the issue by manually remove the dependants first, but is there a one-liner solution that manages the dependencies automatically so that all snaps and snapd can be removed in one go?

Comment: So the design philosophy of snap is to make every package as independent and self-contained as possible? Interesting. But what about stuff like `core18` and `snap-store`? Are they somewhat base/root package needed by all other packages?

Comment: That all starts to make sense now. But just one last question, is there an official command to automatically remove all snap installed packages and snapd as well? I happen to have a small root volume and want to safely clear up `/var/lib/snapd` directory.

Comment: @user535733 You are right. Question edited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove snap from Ubuntu 18.04 (before and after install)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193482/how-to-remove-snap-from-ubuntu-18-04-before-and-after-install)

Comment: @vanadium That answer fails at the first line of `snap list`'s output, which is actually a header line rather than packages. This is easy to fix, though. But what is hard is the dependencies (though there is very few) requires packages to be removed in a specific order, which that answer fails to address as well.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes. Perfect. (Though I did read answers before posting this question, because I see different suggestions on whether to manually remove or not snaps before deleting `snapd` with `apt`. I double checked [the deb packaging script](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/3bec35e7b7241a2682e97a42715d4e4dff7169f8/packaging/debian-sid/snapd.postrm#L142) this time, and I believe the answer you linked will work.

Comment: @wlnirvana glad it helped. I greatly dislike snaps and the instructions linked in one of the answers to that questions are now my standard method for ditching them. https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-snaps-in-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 28):

A one-liner this is not but, if you would like to completely remove everything related to snaps on your machine, follow these steps:

0. Open the Terminal
1. List all the snaps installed on your system with `snap list`. You will see something like this:

   ```
   Name                  Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher         Notes
   chromium              87.0.4280.141               1444   latest/stable    canonical✓        -
   core                  16-2.48.2                   10583  latest/stable    canonical✓        core
   core18                20201210                    1944   latest/stable    canonical✓        base
   emote                 1.3.0                       12     latest/stable    tom-james-watson  -
   gnome-3-28-1804       3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓        -
   gnome-3-34-1804       0+git.3556cb3               66     latest/stable    canonical✓        -
   gnome-system-monitor  3.36.0-12-g35f88a56d7       148    latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
   gtk-common-themes     0.1-50-gf7627e4             1514   latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
   snap-store            3.38.0-59-g494f078          518    latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
   spotify               1.1.46.916.g416cacf1        43     latest/stable    spotify✓          -
   vlc                   3.0.11                      1700   latest/stable    videolan✓         -
   ```
2. Remove each snap that you may have chosen to install using `sudo snap remove <package>`:

   ```
   sudo snap remove chromium
   sudo snap remove emote
   sudo snap remove spotify
   sudo snap remove vlc
   ```
3. Remove the *core* snaps in this order (your list may be slightly different):

   ```
   sudo snap remove snap-store
   sudo snap remove gtk-common-themes
   sudo snap remove gnome-system-monitor
   sudo snap remove gnome-3-34-1804
   sudo snap remove gnome-3-28-1804
   sudo snap remove core18
   sudo snap remove snapd
   ```
4. Verify there are no more snaps installed with `snap list`. You should see a message like this:

   ```
   No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.
   ```
5. Unmount the snap mount points with `sudo umount /snap/core/{point}`, replacing `{point}` with the actual mount point. You can find the complete list using `df -h`.

   ***Note:** In Ubuntu 20.10 (and newer) you only need to do this:* `sudo umount /var/snap`.
6. Remove `snapd` from your system with `sudo apt purge snapd`
7. Remove any snap-related directories that might remain:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/snap
   sudo rm -rf /snap
   sudo rm -rf /var/snap
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/snapd
   ```

Your system will now be devoid of snaps.

Comment: "sudo umount /var/snap" on Ubuntu 20.10:  that is not correct. That is not a mounted directory

Answer (score 14):

You can run:

```
sudo snap remove $(snap list | awk '!/^Name|^core/ {print $1}')
sudo apt remove --purge -y snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

Or in one line:

```
sudo snap remove $(snap list | awk '!/^Name|^core/ {print $1}') && sudo apt remove --purge -y snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

I should add that removing `snapd` and `gnome-software-plugin-snap1` remove also `ubuntu-software`, the Ubuntu software store.  This can be fixed by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

however the icons do not all come back...

Comment: put " && " in between and remove the enter... that makes it a one-liner :D

Comment: @Rinzwind I certainly could, but then it becomes a long command line and looks poorly in my script that I use to setup new machines!

Comment: @CharlesGreen You could then use a ``\`` after the `&&` that Rinzwind suggested, to have your commands as a multiline command. Effectively a one-liner. Also see this relevant SO question: [How to tell bash that the line continues on the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871332/how-to-tell-bash-that-the-line-continues-on-the-next-line)

Comment: Ran into some dependency issues here.. seems like if snap can't remove all specified, it won't remove any.  `snap list | awk '!/^Name|^core/ {print $1}' | xargs -n 1 snap remove` reduced me down to 'core22' and 'snapd' which I removed manually.. I think maybe something in the awk could switch this.