# Ubuntu Software Centershow no application

Tags: 20.04

My Ubuntu software center app doesn't have Visual Studio Code and show no application. Categories also are not working, just showing one blur app and no name in it. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Ubuntu Software screenshot]

Comment: Hey Kaung Kyaw Htin! It will be helpful to us if you add a screenshot of the issue which you are facing. Execute `snap-store` in terminal. Did the app start working now?

Answer (score 1):

[Remove the snap store](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114686/349837) and install Gnome Software
[image]

```
sudo apt autoremove snapd
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: That's quite a radical step, isn't it? Would you mind adding an explanation why would this be a worthy path to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Snap Store shows empty categories (or doesn't show categories at all, only a few software picks on the front page and nothing more) when there are access errors on snapcraft.io server, which recently happens quite often. You can find the error messages in system log, or you can kill the running `snap-store` process and run again `snap-store` in terminal, as said in the comment above. If you see "access denied" errors in `snap-store` output, then something happened again to snapcraft.io server. This is a temporary problem that goes away when they fix the server and it starts to operate normally again.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. It explained the situation very well

Comment: And this is exactly why the user interface **_needs_** a spinner, indicating that the application is waiting for a network response. If something is empty, it's not necessarily because such item does not exist; it can be because the server response with the data is not coming. Huge difference in the conclusion. Some influencers in the user-experience world, several years ago, convinced and scared a large number of designers into not using spinners.

Comment: @Levente In this particular case spinner would not help, as this is an "access denied" error and not a timeout. So the reply **did** come, but the application simply ignores the fact that the reply indicated an error. Snap Store **should** pop up an error message in that case, and not only log it to system logs, where almost nobody would find it.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use snap store, there is an alternative without removing anything.

1. Try to login and go to the user you will sign in on (DON'T ENTER PASSWORD YET)
2. Look for the Gear icon on the lower-left and click it, if there isn't any, enter `sudo apt-get install gnome-settings`
3. Choose Ubuntu or Ubuntu on Xorg(if you dont want to use the wayland windowing system)