# Ubuntu Software application is not loading applications

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 21.04

My Ubuntu Software application doesn't search and load not installed or installed apps. It loads endlessly. I did an update and upgrade my packages via the terminal successfully, and my system, which is Hirsute Hippo, is up to date.

Comment: It appears that [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/) is not available for 21.04 (you can check the dropdown list for "published in" and "hirsute" is not shown). Also, the ukuu package is no longer listed at this ppa for any version of Ubuntu. I'm not sure why it was removed. However, we need to stick to one question at a time so I will remove this from your question. If you need to inquire about ukuu, please open another question but it appears unrelated to your other issue (software center not loading).

Comment: Please look at these answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345515/ubuntu-software-list-is-empty/1345519#1345519 , https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347695/ubuntu-software-not-showing-categories/1347733#1347733 , https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343666/ubuntu-software-centershow-no-application/1343678#1343678