# Ubuntu without containers?

Tags: 20.04, snap, docker, container

Is it possible to configure later (20+) versions of Ubuntu to **NOT** (ever) use containers such as snap and docker?  So tired of seeing these tools consume all the resources.  Would prefer to run natively as this is a stand-alone machine and doesn't need/warrant containers of any type.

Thanks!

--mike

Kind of a follow-up:  If Ubuntu isn't capable of isolating itself from container reliance, is there a linux variant that will?

Comment: I would be careful classifying snaps as "containers".  Containers implies that data on the container can change.  Snaps are confined sandboxed applications whose code is a precompiled/prestored image and *not* able to be edited/revised/adjusted, so I would NOT consider Snaps as containers.  If you don't want to use snaps, simply remove `snapd`.  Same for Docker packages (which are NOT preinstalled on any standard Ubuntu images/installs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove snap from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-from-ubuntu)

Comment: If ANY application "*consume[s] all the resources*", that's likely a bug. Some real troubleshooting is a good idea. I run a half-dozen real LXD containers on very-low-spec hardware, and a couple docker containers on other hardware, and the container overhead is negligible.

Comment: Potato potatoe.

Anything not running natively is a container afaic as it adds some overhead to the existing system.

I shut down a system today where the snaps and containers (for you, Thomas) were spazzing out my system to the point where the cpu was at 3% but load was hovering at over 9.0 and only snaps and dockers headed the active list.  Geh.  Great point about dockers not being native - I've no issue nuking those off the box.  If there's not a native version of a snap app, then I don't need to run it.  Thanks.  Closing.

Comment: Why are you talking about docker? It is not part of the default Ubuntu installation. If you installed docker, you may uninstall it.