# Too much bootup time

Tags: boot

So i have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed on my laptop. It takes more than 2 mins to bootup which seems too much for me. When i had installed Ubuntu on my machine a couple of months ago it didnt take this much time. Here are the logs generated by "systemd-analyze" and "system-analyze blame" respectively

```
isaac@Isaac-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15AST:~$ systemd-analyze
```

`Startup finished in 4.979s (firmware) + 8.472s (loader) + 4.847s (kernel) + 1min 59.732s (userspace) = 2min 18.032s graphical.target reached after 1min 59.606s in userspace`

```
isaac@Isaac-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15AST:~$ systemd-analyze blame
```

`1min 22.046s fstrim.service`

```
 57.290s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 37.756s systemd-journal-flush.service
 33.487s dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2droot.device
 31.672s apt-daily.service
 26.775s snapd.service
 23.608s logrotate.service
 21.060s networkd-dispatcher.service
 20.841s snap-bare-5.mount
 19.967s snap-core18-2714.mount
 19.579s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 19.316s snap-core18-2721.mount
 18.666s udisks2.service
 18.013s snap-core20-1778.mount
 16.502s snap-core20-1852.mount
 13.452s snap-core22-583.mount
 13.435s ModemManager.service
 13.344s accounts-daemon.service
 13.160s dev-loop28.device
 13.022s dev-loop19.device
 12.719s dev-loop18.device
 12.715s dev-loop23.device
 12.713s dev-loop26.device
```

Also here are my specs

```
CPU : AMD® A6-9225 radeon r4, 5 compute cores 2c+3g × 2
GPU : No external. iGPU (STONEY (stoney, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-69-generic))
HDD : 1TB
RAM : 4GB 
OS  : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (64 bit)
SSD : No SSD
```

So is there any solution to this problem? Also is there any fault in my system or do i just need to upgrade my hardware...?

[Solved] Thanks to @Archisman Panigrahi i was able to remove all the snap apps and the snap itself which decreased my bootup time at a noticable degree. Here are the logs after removing snap

`isaac@Isaac-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15AST:~$ systemd-analyze`

```
Startup finished in 5.810s (firmware) + 5.990s (loader) + 5.145s (kernel) + 1min 35.600s (userspace) = 1min 52.547s
graphical.target reached after 1min 35.524s in userspace
```

`isaac@Isaac-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15AST:~$ systemd-analyze blame`

```
49.362s plymouth-quit-wait.service
31.030s systemd-journal-flush.service
23.653s dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2droot.device
17.721s systemd-udevd.service
16.684s networkd-dispatcher.service
15.613s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
13.481s udisks2.service
10.818s accounts-daemon.service
 8.654s ModemManager.service
 7.616s power-profiles-daemon.service
 7.567s polkit.service
 7.249s cups.service
 7.019s gdm.service
 6.680s NetworkManager.service
 6.674s bluetooth.service
 6.170s switcheroo-control.service
 6.134s thermald.service
 6.133s systemd-logind.service
 5.845s wpa_supplicant.service
 4.695s systemd-resolved.service
 3.518s rsyslog.service
 3.078s apparmor.service
 2.785s e2scrub_reap.service
```

Comment: HDDs are slow to boot from, get an SSD.

Comment: Some settings to review, and more links to additional suggestions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster I find Kubuntu a bit faster, but still has everything I want. And SSD does make a huge difference. They are not as expensive anymore and you still can use an HDD for backup or data.

Comment: A combination of only 4GB RAM and a slow hard disk.

Comment: A previous comment I made had my server booting at 2 minutes 43 seconds.  But following through and removing unnecessary snaps (like in the answer below) from the system I was able to cut down the boot time of my server with HDDs only to 1 minute 28 seconds.

Comment: Old HD so why is fstrim. service active?

Comment: @nobody dont know why fstrim.service was active before. Though after removing snap i cant find it in the logs generated by 'systemd-analyze blame'. Feeling kinda weird...

Comment: @Tenkyless Can you check out the updated answer, and confirm if removing the log files as I described helps to speed up?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi well i did. I didnt see any change in my bootup time. Its still around 1 min 55 sec ( 1 min 56.22s to be exact ). But i did see some noticeable change in my 'systemd-analyze blame' log. Dont know why my bootup time didnt change though. I can upload the logs if you want.

Comment: @Tenkyless I don't think the boot speed can be improved any further (unless you disable important system services which you may not use). You don't have to upload new logs.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi ahh i see... Also is there a possibility that my fstab file is causing the bootup issue..? Except for the /boot/efi no other mount point have any UUID associated with them... Also my fstab looks kinda messed up compared to others....

Comment: @Tenkyless You can ask a new question about fstab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logs say that snap events take a lot of time in boot. I too have personally experienced this issue in older computers with HDDs, where removing snap improved the boot speed considerably. Replace all snap apps with apt apps, and uninstall snapd.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466) is how to replace Firefox snap, if you use Firefox, and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/124466) is how to remove snapd altogether.

---

You can also disable `apt-daily.service` (then you will have to regularly check for updates manually, and keep your system updated).

```
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service
```

---

Also, `systemd-journal-flush.service` is taking a lot of time. So, clearing the systemd logs can speed up the boot process further.

```
sudo journalctl --flush --rotate
sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=20M
```

---

You can also safely disable `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Comment: Great answer here!  +1  However, it is yucky that Canonical Livepatch is only available via Snap.  Grrrr!! But removing all the other garbage like the Snap Firefox, etc I was able to cut the boot time of my server by over half!  :)

Comment: OP seems to be using an old Ideapad. It is unlikely that they would need livepatch.

Comment: My point being is that I really dislike snaps, but Canonical is making this tough on those of us that prefer LTS releases but don't want to reboot servers as often.

Comment: @Terrance Hmmm.