# glibc version issue while using prisma on ubuntu

Tags: 23.10, glibc

I got this error while using prisma in Nextjs on ubuntu :

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error:
> Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:

> Unable to require(`/media/waris/DEV/My courses/nextjs-prisma/blog-course/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-3.0.x.so.node`).
> Prisma has detected an incompatible version of the `glibc` C standard library installed in your system.
> This probably means your system may be too old to run Prisma. Please refer to the documentation about Prisma's system requirements: https://pris.ly/d/system-requirements

> Details: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3)

[Here is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLghh.png)

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try using a non-snap version. Your snap wrongly uses core20, whereas it would need at least core22.

Comment: @DanielT I didn't setup prisma using snap

Comment: I see `/snap/core20/[...]`. To make sure, you can uninstall snap then try again: https://askubuntu.com/q/1035915/1004020

Comment: Ok but I think it won't uninstall all the apps I already install using snap