GUI option to remove snaps?
I would like to use normal apt packages, and not be redirected to snap when I do sudo apt install chromium-browser. How do I toggle this off? I can't find it in the settings.

Have a look at this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/124466. It tells you how to mark snapd on hold so that it is not accidentally installed when you install something like Chromium. It also tells you how to add a GUI software center afterward that does not pull snap packages.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I was hoping there would be a way to do it in Settings, but it seems Ubuntu is stubborn on having the snaps. I was successful using a method similar to the one you linked, but it is not ideal, and for me this keeps Linux for those you understand computers well, I could not trust on the average person configuring this.

Ubuntu is forcibly pushing snaps for the last few years. If you want a simple OS that does not require so much effort to get rid of snap, use Linux Mint instead. Ubuntu expects the "average users" to just use snaps. Just like Windows expects average users to use .exe.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I will try Linux Mint when it moves to 24.04, thank you!

You can not. You need to manually block the snap version and install the other one yourself (by adding a 3rd party PPA). If you do not, even if you install the apt version, when the snap version gets a newer version number it would replace the apt version.
An exception to this would be a source install (you download the tar.gz, extract it in /opt/ (as that is the intended directory for source installs) and then use the executable in /opt/).
