# How can I replace Snap application such as Gnome Calculator with a deb?

Tags: 18.04, snap

So, thanks to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1575053 I would rather not use Snap packages. The only one that I really use is Calculator but I would like to replace all of them with a deb version. How would I go about it?

Comment: Can you not uninstall it and then install it via `apt` ?

Comment: you can just hide the `~/snap` folder following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/882964/810348). If you want to stop using the whole Snapd ecosystem you may try my answer [down below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039434/810348)

Comment: Yes, but hten I still get to see it in terminal.

Comment: A couple of other shortcomings that make the snap apps a downgrade from a UX perspective over their traditional APT counterparts (that were stock in 17.10):
1. They're noticeably slower to launch (even on a 1 year old flagship laptop)
2. They don't adjust to system-wide themeing
Hopefully these shortcomings will be resolved soon but until then [Eskander's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039434/145568) is a very nice and easy fix.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This answer is for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The version 16.04 LTS came with the deb version by default and not the snap version.

## The Graphical way

Click on the **Ubuntu Software** icon and search for **gnome-calc**:

[image]

To verify which is which, click on each one in turn. When you click on the installed version and scroll down you will see:

[image]

Note the **Snap Store** at the bottom

When you click on the second one and scroll down you will see:

[image]

Now you can click on <kbd>Remove</kbd> button for the snap version to remove it. Similarly click on the <kbd>Install</kbd> button to install the deb version. In both cases you will be asked for the password.

## The command line way

Open a terminal by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter to following to remove the snap version:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
```

and enter the following to install the deb version:

```
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```

You will be prompted for your password. Unlike the graphical method, you will not see any ***** and the cursor will not move when you type your password. This is normal.

Hope this helps

Comment: Also, note that removing Snap packages are usually safe since snaps supplies its own libraries in their install. (much like Windows program installation and its .db files)

Answer (score 42):

Snap packages installed by default in **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** are:

- `gnome-calculator`
- `gnome-characters`
- `gnome-logs`
- `gnome-system-monitor`

Which can be found using the command `sudo snap list`. To remove default **Snap** apps use:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-logs gnome-system-monitor
```

Then install their **.deb** counterparts with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-logs gnome-system-monitor
```

Additionaly, you can uninstall the whole **Snapd ecosystem** from your computer with:

```
sudo apt purge snapd squashfs-tools gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

Comment: Gnoem characters says `sudo snap remove gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-logs gnome-system-monitor`

Comment: @sup I'm not sure I understand

Comment: No, of course not, wrong paste, sorry, I meant: `sudo apt install gnome-characters` gives`Package gnome-characters is not available, but is referred to by another package.`

Comment: this is strange, I'm quite sure that's what the package is called on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-characters) and on  [launhpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/gnome-characters). did you try `sudo apt update` before installing?

Comment: Indeed, updating the database help, not sure why the other packages installed correctly, thanks! I accepted the other answer as I think it is easier to follow, I actually used your solution, being a friend of th ecommand line. And I should look it up myself.

Comment: the graphical way involves checking whether every single app is a snap or not, I'm not sure if that's easier

Comment: What about `/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/`, which appears to be *Ubuntu Desktop* ? Any way of replacing those with `apt` packages?

Comment: @FooBar that one is an [SDK for GNOME snap apps](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Community/Ubuntu/gnome-3-28-1804-sdk) and not an actual program. If you don't plan on using snaps you won't need it.

Comment: (i) You're linking to 28-1804, are you certain it's the same? (ii) Your list came across as exhaustive, yet I find that package and `core` installed, which I did not add -- I installed barebones version of the latest Ubuntu LTS. Were they both preinstalled?

Comment: Yep not the same, I linked a newer one but same concept. And `core` is part of Snapd, which gets deleted along with it

Comment: Kudo for mentioning which gnome default comes as snap, thanks.

Comment: This is insane. I was wondering why calculator suddenly takes so long to load. This will probably make me get rid of ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all snap packages except `core` and `core18` in one command

```
sudo snap remove `sudo snap list | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n 2 | grep -v 'core' | tr '\n' ' '`
```

To finish purging do like mentioned above:

```
sudo apt -y purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

I'm assuming you might seen `squashfs-tools` in another package