# Snaps delay boot by creating loops?

Tags: boot, snap

I just updated to 18.04, and facing a slow boot I ran the following:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
         14.760s dev-sda5.device
         13.228s systemd-journal-flush.service
         12.607s dev-loop1.device
         12.537s dev-loop0.device
         12.486s dev-loop2.device
         12.453s dev-loop4.device
         12.423s dev-loop3.device
         12.375s dev-loop6.device
         12.344s dev-loop7.device
         12.331s dev-loop5.device
         12.299s dev-loop8.device
         12.279s dev-loop10.device
         12.263s dev-loop9.device
         12.223s dev-loop11.device
         10.228s apparmor.service
          9.953s systemd-udevd.service
          9.155s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          7.387s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          4.037s udisks2.service
          4.001s snapd.service
          3.950s NetworkManager.service
          2.964s plymouth-start.service
          2.906s ModemManager.service
          2.809s accounts-daemon.service
          2.756s grub-common.service
          2.045s networkd-dispatcher.service
          1.852s avahi-daemon.service
          1.791s thermald.service
          1.274s wpa_supplicant.service
          1.224s keyboard-setup.service
          1.082s fwupd.service
```

and next

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop1    7:1    0    21M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop2    7:2    0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop3    7:3    0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/spotify/16
loop4    7:4    0 124.3M  1 loop /snap/thunderbird/3
loop5    7:5    0   1.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop6    7:6    0   3.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
loop7    7:7    0  12.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop8    7:8    0 299.9M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-professional/68
loop9    7:9    0   198M  1 loop /snap/vlc/365
loop10   7:10   0 139.4M  1 loop /snap/chromium/343
loop11   7:11   0   4.9M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/41
loop12   7:12   0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4650
loop13   7:13   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/41
loop14   7:14   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/170
loop15   7:15   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/34
loop16   7:16   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/96
loop17   7:17   0 139.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   248G  0 part /media/foo/4afaaee5-473b-41c9-acd0-506a3566fcf5
├─sda5   8:5    0 201.9G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

It appears that my main device takes 14 seconds (not sure if that's a lot), but then all these loop devices (snaps?) add up a lot of time too. Is that normal behavior? Is there any other way to reduce boot time other than uninstalling them?

Comment: If not using them, you can uninstall. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb Snaps may have a place where an older app could then use different dependancies that your install has. But for current software in current system, I do not see much advantage.

Comment: This is how i understand they work. Not sure why they don't just do this when you start the individual app. I hope they just redo snaps to essentially work differently. Don't know who actually thought a robust solutions would make every app you install slow your startup time for your computer. Also i hear performance is terrible for apps due to squashfs but i'm not well educated on that