# Ubuntu 18.04 take too long time in boot

Tags: 18.04, reboot

My Ubuntu 18.04 machine takes too long time in startup time.
When I run this command `systemd-analyze blame` I have this output in terminal:

```
6.595s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          4.349s postgresql@10-main.service
          4.216s dev-sda1.device
          3.910s dev-loop23.device
          3.905s dev-loop20.device
          3.895s dev-loop21.device
          3.882s dev-loop22.device
          3.879s dev-loop16.device
          3.847s dev-loop18.device
          3.815s dev-loop24.device
          3.784s dev-loop19.device
          3.771s dev-loop15.device
          3.709s dev-loop14.device
          3.696s dev-loop17.device
          3.331s dev-loop9.device
          3.320s dev-loop6.device
          3.318s dev-loop2.device
          3.315s dev-loop8.device
          3.315s dev-loop0.device
          3.314s dev-loop1.device
          3.313s dev-loop3.device
          3.304s dev-loop4.device
          3.283s dev-loop10.device
          3.281s dev-loop13.device
          3.275s dev-loop7.device
```

What can I do for `dev-loopx.device` ?

Edit1: the output of command `systemd-analyze critical-chain` is:

```
graphical.target @10.784s
└─multi-user.target @10.784s
  └─kerneloops.service @10.690s +93ms
    └─network-online.target @10.685s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @4.046s +6.637s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.648s +1.396s
          └─dbus.service @2.099s
            └─basic.target @2.006s
              └─sockets.target @2.006s
                └─docker.socket @2.001s +3ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.988s
                    └─apparmor.service @557ms +1.407s
                      └─local-fs.target @551ms
                        └─local-fs-pre.target @530ms
                          └─keyboard-setup.service @257ms +272ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @239ms
                              └─system.slice @238ms
                                └─-.slice @233ms
```

Edit2: the command:`df -kh` output is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           375M  1.7M  373M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       110G   20G   85G  20% /
tmpfs           1.9G   21M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2      142M  142M     0 100% /snap/skype/38
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop1      565M  565M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/58
/dev/loop3      565M  565M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/56
/dev/loop4       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4830
/dev/loop5      138M  138M     0 100% /snap/skype/33
/dev/loop6       21M   21M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/25
/dev/loop9      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop7      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
/dev/loop8       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop10     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/41
/dev/loop15      87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop13     2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/170
/dev/loop12      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/101
/dev/loop14      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/34
/dev/loop11     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop16     2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/178
/dev/loop20     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/45
/dev/loop17     2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop19     133M  133M     0 100% /snap/skype/41
/dev/loop22      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/96
/dev/loop18     565M  565M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/60
/dev/loop23     140M  140M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/loop21      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop24      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
tmpfs           375M   40K  375M   1% /run/user/1000
```

edit3: the result after removing **Snapd ecosystem** with this command :

sudo apt purge snapd squashfs-tools gnome-software-plugin-snap

the result for  `systemd-analyze blame` is:

```
 6.566s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          4.177s postgresql@10-main.service
          2.782s dev-sda1.device
          1.788s udisks2.service
          1.721s NetworkManager.service
          1.670s accounts-daemon.service
          1.549s ModemManager.service
          1.410s mysql.service
          1.385s networkd-dispatcher.service
           913ms apparmor.service
           900ms fwupd.service
           898ms polkit.service
           812ms setvtrgb.service
           634ms systemd-rfkill.service
           629ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           597ms grub-common.service
           589ms avahi-daemon.service
           543ms systemd-logind.service
           537ms wpa_supplicant.service
           529ms apport.service
           528ms zookeeper.service
           501ms thermald.service
           457ms networking.service
```

but the boot time is about 250s.

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the output of `df -kh`? I have a feeling these are snap images.

Comment: Also check `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Maybe all those snaps aren't delaying anything after all.

Comment: @ user535733 I have edited with your command

Comment: @Generic you made a mistake with the command proposed by G Trawo : it was `df -kh`, not `systemd-analyze -kh`

Comment: Are you using the snaps?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb
boot time cut in half by removing snap
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391341

Comment: @oldfred I have removed snap and now booting time has increased to about 4 min. I added the edit3 result.

Comment: Could you please check if you're affected by https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o and report back? Thanks.

Comment: @ David Foerster I couldn't find the solution by your provided link. Even, I have deleted all snap packages but there is no improvement.