# How to speed up my Ubuntu 18.04 system boot up?

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd, system-settings

After upgrading to Linux 18.04 my system boot up has become really very slow. I tried to find the reason for it using the systemd-analyze blame and it showed me the below results:

```
    45.857s systemd-journal-flush.service
     44.055s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
     39.145s keyboard-setup.service
     35.135s lvm2-monitor.service
     32.417s systemd-udevd.service
     26.688s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     11.402s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     10.243s mysql.service
      9.523s plymouth-start.service
      8.152s snapd.service
      5.907s NetworkManager.service
      5.526s networkd-dispatcher.service
      5.369s bolt.service
      5.047s udisks2.service
      3.171s postfix@-.service
      3.146s networking.service
      2.923s fwupd.service
      2.889s ModemManager.service
      2.867s wpa_supplicant.service
      2.840s thermald.service
      2.678s accounts-daemon.service
      2.555s gpu-manager.service
      2.434s rsyslog.service
```

Is there any way to enhance the system boot up process as the boot process has deteriorated from seconds to minutes ?

Comment: That does not look like the complete output of  'blame'. Without complete information, you may get bad advice. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. It's more useful than 'blame'

Comment: My situation may be different than yours, but you might be able to eliminate some services if you are not using them:  `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` waits for the network to be active for example, and `plymouth-quit-wait.service` can be bypassed by not using the `splash` setting in grub.

Comment: Old thread, some may still apply. https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed and Do you use snaps? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb Boot time quicker without snaps.

Comment: @user535733 I have reposted the question with all the mentioned details :
       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104284/how-to-enhance-my-system-boot-up-speed

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Please delete one or the other. Thanks!