# How to enhance my system boot up speed

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd, system-settings

After upgrading to Linux 18.04 my system boot up has become really very slow. I tried to find the reason for it using the systemd-analyze blame and it showed me the below results:

```
     44.055s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
     39.145s keyboard-setup.service
     35.135s lvm2-monitor.service
     26.688s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     11.402s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     10.243s mysql.service
      9.523s plymouth-start.service
      8.152s snapd.service
      5.907s NetworkManager.service
      5.526s networkd-dispatcher.service
      5.133s bolt.service
      5.047s udisks2.service
      3.146s networking.service
      2.889s ModemManager.service
      2.867s wpa_supplicant.service
      2.840s thermald.service
      2.678s accounts-daemon.service
      2.555s gpu-manager.service
      2.057s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.838s systemd-sysctl.service
      1.675s snap-core18-442.mount
      1.521s snap-core18-512.mount
      1.443s snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2di386-22.mount
      1.431s snap-skype-63.mount
      1.394s snap-chromium-550.mount
      1.387s avahi-daemon.service
      1.355s snap-notepadqq-855.mount
      1.306s bluetooth.service
      1.166s apparmor.service
      1.157s snap-core-6034.mount
      1.142s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-808.mount
      1.141s snap-skype-66.mount
      1.140s snap-skype-60.mount
      1.121s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-701.mount
      1.106s snap-core-5897.mount
      1.102s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount
      1.069s upower.service
      1.063s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.006s user@121.service
       982ms dev-loop17.device
       973ms dev-hugepages.mount
       972ms dev-mqueue.mount
       937ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       911ms lvm2-pvscan@8:2.service
       882ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       857ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       788ms plymouth-read-write.service
       786ms polkit.service
       779ms snap-core18-536.mount
       770ms snap-chromium-538.mount
       754ms fwupd.service
       733ms netfilter-persistent.service
       732ms systemd-rfkill.service
       727ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       596ms ssh.service
       542ms snap-chromium-562.mount
       513ms systemd-logind.service
       481ms binfmt-support.service
       462ms dns-clean.service
       442ms blk-availability.service
       436ms dev-loop11.device
       425ms ufw.service
       372ms dev-loop6.device
       361ms dev-loop15.device
       343ms gdm.service
       325ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2di386-25.mount
       312ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       299ms dev-loop13.device
       294ms setvtrgb.service
       272ms snap-core-6130.mount
       256ms boot-efi.mount
       248ms systemd-resolved.service
       219ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2di386-23.mount
       208ms user@1000.service
       207ms systemd-random-seed.service
       200ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       196ms dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.swap
       191ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       187ms dev-loop4.device
       181ms speech-dispatcher.service
       176ms postfix@-.service
       173ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-62E7\x2dA5B2.service
       163ms dev-loop5.device
       146ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       140ms systemd-journald.service
       125ms colord.service
       103ms dev-loop8.device
       100ms dev-loop14.device
        94ms xinetd.service
        89ms grub-common.service
        77ms dev-loop10.device
        42ms snapd.seeded.service
        37ms systemd-udevd.service
        29ms dev-loop18.device
        27ms kerneloops.service
        26ms virtualbox.service
        24ms snapd.socket
        18ms packagekit.service
        17ms alsa-restore.service
        15ms dev-loop16.device
        14ms dev-loop1.device
        13ms dev-loop3.device
        12ms dev-loop0.device
        12ms dev-loop2.device
        11ms dev-loop9.device
        10ms dev-loop7.device
        10ms dev-loop12.device
         9ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
         8ms apport.service
         7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         7ms ureadahead-stop.service
         6ms rtkit-daemon.service
         6ms pppd-dns.service
         6ms console-setup.service
         5ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         3ms systemd-journal-flush.service
         2ms rsyslog.service
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         1ms postfix.service
         1ms openbsd-inetd.service
```

Upon doing the same with systemd-analyze critical-chain I received the below results:

```
       graphical.target @1min 27.232s
        └─xinetd.service @1min 11.939s +94ms
           └─network-online.target @1min 11.935s
              └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 531ms +11.402s
               └─NetworkManager.service @54.622s +5.907s
                 └─dbus.service @54.541s
                  └─basic.target @54.530s
                   └─sockets.target @54.530s
                    └─snapd.socket @54.505s +24ms
                     └─sysinit.target @54.504s
                      └─apparmor.service @53.336s +1.166s
                       └─local-fs.target @53.331s
                         └─run-user-121.mount @1min 3.281s
                           └─swap.target @53.986s
                            └─dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.swap @53.789s +196ms
                              └─dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.device @53.787s
```

Is there any possibility of enhancing the boot up process as the boot up process interval has deteriorated from seconds to minutes ?

Comment: I don't have privileges to edit the question Sir so I had to repost it

Comment: The question which I posted in the first place Sir. The comment asked me to add more details so had to repost it because I don't find a way of editing the question Sir.

Comment: Are you using NetworkManager or netplan for your network configuration? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. You also have a lot of snap applications that slow down the boot up.

Comment: @Kulfy okay great Sir I will ofcourse go through it . Can we please focus on the issue at hand ?

Comment: The issue at hand is slow boot up... I'm trying to focus on that by starting to ask some relevant questions...

Comment: @heynema                                                                                                         # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
          version: 2
         renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: Are you able to uninstall the snap applications and install similar apps from the Ubuntu Software store, or Synaptic, or from the terminal?

Comment: Name                Version         Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
    chromium            71.0.3578.98    562   stable    canonical*  -
    core                16-2.36.3       6130  stable    canonical*  core
    core18              18              536   stable    canonical*  base
    gtk-common-themes   0.1-4-g88bc1b2  818   stable    canonical*  -
    notepadqq           1.4.8           855   stable    danieleds   -
    skype               8.34.0.78       66    stable    skype*      classic
    wine-platform-i386  1.0             25    stable    mmtrt       -

Comment: Your network is taking some time to connect, and your snaps (of which there appear to be duplicate mounts) may be taking the longest. Are you using DHCP or manual in your network connection scripts? Are you using wired or wireless? Can you convert your snap apps to non-snap apps... as each snap uses system resources. Show me `free -h`. Click the `edit` to add that info to your question.

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    
Mem:           7.7G        1.9G        4.0G        258M        1.7G        5.2G

Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G

Comment: @heynnema can you please help how to check in network connection scripts. I use wifi connection to connect to internet

Comment: Disconnect from the wi-fi, reconnect, and time how long it takes to get a full connection. Are you using WPA2-AES? To check wi-fi connection scripts, open settings, go to wi-fi, find your wi-fi name, click the circular wheel on the right, and look under ipv4, should be dhcp. Are you able to do anything with the snaps?

Comment: @Fabby no, but it IS a dup of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104272/how-to-speed-up-my-ubuntu-18-04-system-boot-up, which I've marked to close.

Comment: Yeah, saw that later when I went backwards into the Question queue @heynnema.  If I retract my CV, I won't be able to CV any more on this Q though...  But if you say the magic word in Dutch, I will retract.  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby  Nah... we'd like to keep you in the loop here :-) fyi: my parents are Dutch :-)

Comment: Ah, I thought you were a Dutchman living in the Republic of California, but you're a Californian with a Dutch name...  **;-)** (I'm neither: I'm a Vorlon) @heynnema