# Ubuntu installation on ssd, hdd and ramdisk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu (with kde-plasma) windows 10 is currently on my SSD and Ubuntu is on my HDD but Ubuntu is reallyyyy slow right now and i want to speed up it should i reinstall the Ubuntu on my SSD near to the windows 10? how can i do this or i can use ramdisk for some speedup i/o or sth. some forums says usr/local should be on SSD and home on HDD whats are them and my new programs that i installed on Ubuntu where are they going? idk.

thats my laptop specs:

- 16gb ram (i have more than ram that i used gerenally so i want to use it for sth like ramdisk to speed up system)
- 256gb nvme-ssd
- 1tb hdd
- i7-8750H

i am gonna use Ubuntu for coding java and js and daily use.

my current partition details:

- SSD: windows efi and windows partition
- HDD: storage + Ubuntu efi + Ubuntu partition + swap

i have 2 efi partitions so i select disks from bios instead of using grub menu.

i am planning to do this:

- SSD: windows efi and windows partition + Ubuntu partition(is 50gb enough?)
- HDD: storage + Ubuntu efi + swap + (maybe some Ubuntu partitions such as home tmp sth)

---

```
mert@canavarrlinuxx:~$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 4.664s (kernel) + 1min 28.363s (userspace) = 1min 33.027s
graphical.target reached after 39.415s in userspace

mert@canavarrlinuxx:~$ systemd-analyze blame
         48.955s apt-daily.service
         20.007s dev-sda3.device
         11.853s systemd-journal-flush.service
         10.991s systemd-udevd.service
          9.993s systemd-modules-load.service
          8.453s plymouth-start.service
          6.839s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.318s dev-loop12.device
          6.204s dev-loop9.device
          6.193s dev-loop8.device
          6.169s dev-loop10.device
          6.165s dev-loop11.device
          6.141s dev-loop14.device
          6.122s dev-loop15.device
          6.097s dev-loop18.device
          6.074s dev-loop19.device
          5.924s dev-loop0.device
          5.683s dev-loop17.device
          5.637s dev-loop6.device
          5.394s dev-loop13.device
          5.289s dev-loop1.device
          5.289s dev-loop2.device
          5.278s dev-loop3.device
          5.257s dev-loop4.device
          5.257s dev-loop5.device
          5.231s dev-loop7.device
          4.542s keyboard-setup.service
          4.390s dev-loop16.device
          3.866s grub-common.service
          3.808s NetworkManager.service
          3.525s apparmor.service
lines 1-31
```

---

i also have this problem i know what is the bad sector but my disk is kinda new its been just 6 months how could it be? and it says healt though???

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ZGL7wT8p5yMxgRnlMhay0ZfamVXztE6/view?usp=sharing

```
mert@canavarrlinuxx:~$ systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
UNIT FILE                                             STATE  
snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-54.mount                  enabled
snap-core-4917.mount                                  enabled
snap-core-6259.mount                                  enabled
snap-core-6350.mount                                  enabled
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount                enabled
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount                enabled
snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount                    enabled
snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount                    enabled
snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount                    enabled
snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount                    enabled
snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount                           enabled
snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount                           enabled
snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount              enabled
snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount              enabled
snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount                enabled
snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount                enabled
snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-184.mount                enabled
snap-ubuntu\x2dcalculator\x2dapp-20.mount             enabled
snap-vlc-770.mount                                    enabled
snap-wine\x2dplatform-74.mount                        enabled
acpid.path                                            enabled
apport-autoreport.path                                enabled
cups.path                                             enabled
lines 1-24...skipping...
UNIT FILE                                             STATE                                                                                                                                                
snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-54.mount                  enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-core-4917.mount                                  enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-core-6259.mount                                  enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-core-6350.mount                                  enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount                enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount                enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount                    enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount                    enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount                    enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount                    enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount                           enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount                           enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount              enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount              enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount                enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount                enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-184.mount                enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-ubuntu\x2dcalculator\x2dapp-20.mount             enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-vlc-770.mount                                    enabled                                                                                                                                              
snap-wine\x2dplatform-74.mount                        enabled                                                                                                                                              
acpid.path                                            enabled                                                                                                                                              
apport-autoreport.path                                enabled                                                                                                                                              
cups.path                                             enabled                                                                                                                                              
accounts-daemon.service                               enabled                                                                                                                                              
anacron.service                                       enabled                                                                                                                                              
apparmor.service                                      enabled                                                                                                                                              
autovt@.service                                       enabled                                                                                                                                              
avahi-daemon.service                                  enabled                                                                                                                                              
bluetooth.service                                     enabled
console-setup.service                                 enabled
cron.service                                          enabled
cups-browsed.service                                  enabled
cups.service                                          enabled
dbus-fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service                    enabled
dbus-org.bluez.service                                enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service                    enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service            enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service            enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service                 enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.thermald.service                 enabled
dns-clean.service                                     enabled
getty@.service                                        enabled
gpu-manager.service                                   enabled
irqbalance.service                                    enabled
kerneloops.service                                    enabled
keyboard-setup.service                                enabled
ModemManager.service                                  enabled
network-manager.service                               enabled
networkd-dispatcher.service                           enabled
networking.service                                    enabled
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service                     enabled
NetworkManager-wait-online.service                    enabled

mert@canavarrlinuxx:~$
```

Comment: What about ubuntu is slow? Slow to boot? Slow to open programs? Slow to do large computations? Slow to compile? It'd be worth defining what you mean by slow, as well as determining the root cause of such a slow down rather than just obliterating your current install.

Comment: For the record my ubuntu machine which is running on a 5 year old HDD boots in about 11s and I am able to jump to a command line nearly instantly, and the hardware is significantly worse than yours.

Comment: If you add a new install to an ext4 as / (root) on SSD you can make it 25GB. I use 25 or 30 GB for / but actual use in that is less than 10GB. But I have all the data in /home really in HDD and folders linked back to /home in /. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk Check mounted partitions: `df -h` and folder sizes: cd / or cd /home
`sudo du -hc --max-depth=1`

Comment: @j-money ubuntu boots about 1minutes (windows is about 15sec) and programs are opening slowly it looks like some lag or response time is so high i am clicking for the terminal and waiting 2-3 seconds?? i also use intelij-idea sometimes when i first time opened it respons slowly menus and even typing after a while it backs to the normal. by the way i have installed kde-plasma desktop does it matter?

Comment: @oldfred so okey then i am gonna shrink 40gb from my ssd and install the root there and home to my hdd? is this just fine?

Comment: output of `systemd-analyze time` and `systemd-analyze blame`?

Comment: it is too long to put here so i have putted it to answers but it dont see the endlines or enters ? i am new i this forum so :D

Comment: Next time just edit your original post with the 'edit' button (I've done it for you this time) as for slow boot times, look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: Also you might have other errors you haven't noticed `11.853s  systemd-journal-flush.service ` this seems weird to me (fwiw, that has an output of 235ms on my system)... output of `systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f3TYE5SLZ7PqGEVMt8NiaOqD2nJH_B8e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @j-money everything is enabled

Comment: Is it running fsck on every reboot on your sda3 partition? And I am not a fan of snaps. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2411218 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb

Comment: "everything is enabled" - @TelefonMakinesi That's your problem, if you have everything under the sun enabled, your computer may never boot... Now i ask again, output of `systemctl list-unit-files --enabled`

Comment: @j-money i've editted and added it.

Comment: Whatever you've done to this system is causing slow boot times, not your hdd so reinstalling on an ssd you may see marginal performance. See my comment a few comments up

Comment: @j-money probably you are right. thanks a lot to everybody. i will reinstall the ubuntu.