# Ubuntu 18.04 pypy3 package

Tags: apt, 18.04, ppa

I tried installing *pypy3* after installing *pypy* through the regular Ubuntu 18.04 repo:

```
E: Unable to locate package pypy3
```

Okay, so it's not available in the regular repos. I added the official [PyPy PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pypy/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) as suggested on the [PyPy download page](https://pypy.org/download.html):

```
E: Unable to locate package pypy3
```

Again, *pypy3* is not available. Is there really no *pypy3* package available for Ubuntu, or am I missing something that should be obvious?

Comment: There is a snap version of pypy3.  `sudo snap install pypy3 --classic`.  And if you want the newest version it would be `sudo snap install pypy3 --edge --classic` and if you want to change between the two the command is `sudo snap refresh pypy3 --edge --classic` or `sudo snap refresh pypy3 --stable --classic`.

Comment: @Terrance I'm manually installing it. Snap pollutes the home directory because it ignores XDG and other standards.

Comment: @Terrance Etiquette might be a better description. It's weird that it installs things under `/snap` and ensures `~/snap` exists instead of say `~/.snap`.

Comment: I get what you're saying.  Looks like it is a bug that people have filed and marked as affects them as well.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/882562/how-can-i-change-or-hide-the-snap-directory