# When I install applications with snap, i always have to start them as root. How do I fix that?

Tags: root, snap

Additionally to that, I tried to install an application on ubuntu using `snap install`, which is originally a windows application which used wine in the background.
This application was pretty huge and I realized there, that it got installed in the root directory bcs it filled the complete free disk space of the root partition. How can I change the directory or fix that I have to execute applications installed by snap as root?

Comment: which app are you looking to run?

Comment: @tatsu that was a game <br> http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/09/install-league-of-legends-ubuntu-snap/

Comment: which one? I can give you a step by step.

Comment: oh I used that snap! it works well for me, but yeah, the constraint is it is home dir-only. sorry you'll have to use Lutris instead. a tiny bit less user-friendly than a simple `sudo apt install ...` but still really straightforward. it's the same exact tech used under the hood anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so snaps, as it turns out, are not all they're cracked up to be.

sure it circumvents dependency issues but as a con, you have to wait for it to start up your transparent emulated environement, so a longer startup time, not a hassle in your case since your snap is for a windows binary anyways so you'd have this extra startup in any event.

the problem, however, is that snaps can [apparently](https://askubuntu.com/a/882622/307184) not be elsewhere than your home.

I'd wager moving the dirrectory of your app inside the ~/snap dir to another hard drive and running it from there should be doable but, you run into the issue of not even having enough space in Home at **download** so that's a no-go.

It looks to me as if you'd be better served installing the app in question via a more powerfull method, such as [lutris](https://lutris.net/) (or [steam](https://store.steampowered.com/)). which allow download to a specific destination and much more configurability.