# How to prevent an application from creating folder in my home directory?

Tags: home-directory, filemanager, directory-structure

It's really annoying that some applications are polluting my home directories. For example, MindMaster, an application developed by Edraw Inc., always creates a folder called `Edraw` in my home directory. (Well, I have to say this company is really awful. Actually, I won't care if it creates '.Edraw'.)

So far, I failed to find `Settings` or `Preference` to solve this problem.

So, I am wondering whether there is a method to prevent file(or folder) with a specific name from creating in a certain directory.

Comment: No. Most applications will need some kind of configuration storage, and home folders are the logical place to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications in linux store their user specific configuration in your Home folder. Applications that behave decently indeed do that in a dedicated hidden folder, i.e., a folder of which the name starts with a dot, so you normally do not see it.

You cannot as such change the location of such program folder unless the application exposes a setting through its options or through a configuration file.

One example of [a very bad choice for a program folder which you cannot change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882562/how-can-i-change-or-hide-the-snap-directory) is the "snap" folder, created by the Snap framework in recent Ubuntu versions. This folder stares right in front at you in your Home folder. As a user, you have to search nothing there, and with a name starting with a lowercase, the folder even stylistically is totally out of place. As a user, you do not have control on that folder.

So the same workaround suggested [in the thread I mentionned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882562/how-can-i-change-or-hide-the-snap-directory) can be used to hide a file on a location you find inconvenient: create a text file with the name `.hidden` in the folder where the unwanted file/folder is, and include its name on a line.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!